# How can I create 2017.11.29 version global table on an existing dynamodb table with data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using lambda as a stream handler on dynamodb table. Whenever there is an update on the table, my lambda will be called to process the change.

Now, I am going to enable global table on dynamodb. I'd like to add a logic in my lambda to check whether the update records from dyanmodb stream is from global table sync or from local region update. In order to do that, I am thinking to use the field `aws:rep:updateregion` created by dynamodb global table. Basically this field tells me the region which this change was made.

However, this field `aws:rep:updateregion` only available in the replica version `2017.11.29`. but I can't create this version of replica on a table with existing data. I can only create it on an empty table.

Below is a screenshot about creating a 2017.11.29 version of replica.

[image]

but for a table with data, I don't see this button:

[image]

So the question is how can I create this version 2017.11.29 replica on a table with some data?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you using SAM or the CDK? Do you have some code?

Comment: sorry for confusing. I updated the question for more information.

Comment: Ah - that means you are already on 2019.11.29

Comment: sorry, I mean create 2017.11.29